# Manipulation event on content of ScatterViewItem

Tags: wpf, 3d, pixelsense, scatterview

I have a Viewport3D object inside a `ScatterViewItem`. I need to rotate the 3D inside without rotating the `ScatterViewItem`. Currently, I am trying to put Manipulation events on the Viewport but they do not fire. All movement gestures are captured by the `ScatterViewItem`, where as I want to send them down the Viewport inside. 
Any help would be of great value.

Thanks,
Bharat Mathur.

Answer (score 0):

`ScatterViewItem` will take control over the touch events only if none of his children in the visual tree didn't mark the routed event as handled.

Since you didn't provide any code sample I can only suggest on optional solutions:
- Try to isolate the problem by taking the viewport3D out from the scatterview - ensure that it without scatterview
- Ensure that the viewport element property 'IsManipulationEnabled' is set to true
- In your touch methods make sure to set 'e.Handled' to 'true'
- Check that the view port hit area is set.

Hope this helps.